# Multiple file upload in KeystoneJs 4.0

Tags: keystonejs

I want to ask a question about multiple file upload in KeystoneJs 4.0.
In version 0.4 there is LocalFiles field, which I think allows you to upload multiple files in a single database record.
How in version 4.0 make downloading multiple files in the album image gallery?
I am trying to do so, and it turns out to download only one file.

My code:

```
var myStorage = new keystone.Storage({
    adapter: keystone.Storage.Adapters.FS,
    fs: {
        path: keystone.expandPath('./public/uploads/gallery/img'), // required; path where the files should be stored
        publicPath: '/public/uploads/gallery/img' // path where files will be served
    }
});

var Gallery = new keystone.List('Gallery', {
    autokey: { from: 'name', path: 'key', unique: true },
    plural: 'Albums',
    singular: 'Album',
});

Gallery.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, default: Date.now },
    images: { type: Types.File, storage: myStorage },
});
```

Comment: I'm confused too. What happened to the file array type?

Comment: From this link it follows that these fields have been deleted in the new version of CMS.
[Upgrade Guide: 0.3 to 4.0](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/docs/guides/v0.3-to-v4.0-Upgrade-Guide.md)

File handling Field Types
New File field type

The new File field type, with the FS, S3 and Azure storage adapters, replace the following field types (which are removed in 0.4) -

azureFile; localFile; localFiles; s3File;